# Solana: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account, Transfer sol to wallet without pri key

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana, solana-program-library, solana-transaction-instruction

I am trying to implement Program Flow of a bet game in solana with following features:

- A Player transfers some amount to house wallet (deposit_wallet) and plays a game
- System records the win loss net balance in a player specific PDA account (player_stats)
- If the net balance is plus a player can withdraw the win amount.
- On withdraw request the program transfers the amount from house wallet (deposit_wallet or separate withdraw_wallet) to the player

Here is the implementation code for instruction

Initialize instruction on first play (works ok):

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(withdraw_bump: u8)]
pub struct RegisterPlayer<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub player: Signer<'info>,
    // space: 8 discriminator + 2 level + 8 balance + 1 latest_result + 1 bump
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = player,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<PlayerStats>(), seeds = [b"player-stats", player.key().as_ref()], bump
    )]
    pub player_stats: Account<'info, PlayerStats>,
    #[account(
      init,
      payer = player,
      space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<Game>(), seeds = [b"game", player.key().as_ref()], bump
    )]
    pub game: Account<'info, Game>,

    #[account(mut, address = Pubkey::from_str(FEE_WALLET).unwrap())]
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write
    pub deposit_wallet: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// CHECK: 
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"withdraw-fund"], bump=withdraw_bump)]

    pub withdraw_fund: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

pub fn register_player(ctx: Context<RegisterPlayer>, _withdraw_bump: u8) -> Result<()> {
  let player_stats = &mut ctx.accounts.player_stats;
  player_stats.level = 0;
  player_stats.win_balance = 0;
  player_stats.latest_result_status = 0;
  player_stats.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("player_stats").unwrap();

  let game = &mut ctx.accounts.game;
  game.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("game").unwrap();
  Ok(())
}
```

Game Play Instruction (works ok):

```
pub struct PlayGame<'info> {
    pub player: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"player-stats", player.key().as_ref()], bump = player_stats.bump)]
    pub player_stats: Account<'info, PlayerStats>,

    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"game", player.key().as_ref()], bump = game.bump)]
    pub game: Account<'info, Game>,

    #[account(mut, address = Pubkey::from_str(FEE_WALLET).unwrap())]
    /// CHECK: Not modifying
    pub deposit_wallet: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

impl<'info> PlayGame<'info> {
    fn transfer_fee_cpi(&self,  amount:u32) -> Result<()> {
        // logic to transfer fee from user account to house account
        // works as expected
        Ok(())
    }
    
    fn play_game(..) {
        // logic to play game
        this.transfer_fee_cpi(amount)
    }

}
```

Claim win amount (throws error):

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(withdraw_bump: u8)]
pub struct ClaimWin<'info> {
    pub player: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
      mut,
      seeds = [b"player-stats", player.key().as_ref()],
      bump = player_stats.bump
    )]
    pub player_stats: Account<'info, PlayerStats>,

    /// CHECK: 
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"withdraw-fund"], bump=withdraw_bump)]
    pub withdraw_fund: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


impl<'info> ClaimWin<'info> {
  fn transfer_win_cpi(&self,  amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
      msg!("cpi transfering win amount {} lambot from [{}] to [{}]", amount, self.withdraw_fund.key , self.player.key);
      msg!("owner of withdraw fund:: {}", self.withdraw_fund.owner);
      
      let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
          self.system_program.to_account_info(), 
          system_program::Transfer {
              from: self.withdraw_fund.to_account_info(),
              to: self.player.to_account_info(),
          });
      system_program::transfer(cpi_context, amount)?;
      
      Ok(())
  }

pub fn claim_win(ctx: Context<ClaimWin>, _withdraw_bump: u8) -> Result<()> {
    const MAXIMUM_LIMIT: u64 = 10000000000;
    let current_balance = ctx.accounts.player_stats.win_balance;

    if current_balance > MAXIMUM_LIMIT {
      return Err(GameError::MaxClaimAmountExceeded.into())
    }

    // transfer to player
    ctx.accounts.transfer_win_cpi(current_balance.clone())?;
    ctx.accounts.player_stats.win_balance = 0;
  
  Ok(())
}
}
```

**Issue**

Although initialize and transfer of sol from player to house wallet in play instruction is working fine, withdrawal from house wallet to player is not working fine with following error

> Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account

Some of my thoughts regarding the issue:

since house wallet private key is not available in the program, planned to use a PDA account instead "withdraw_fund" which in my understanding in owned by the program to make the transfer possible.
*PDA*

```
    /// CHECK: // TODO: make better seed
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"withdraw-fund"], bump=withdraw_bump)]
    pub withdraw_fund: AccountInfo<'info>,
```

Tried using custom state struct instead of `AccountInfo` but need of `init` didn't make sense for this.

Transfer from withdraw_fund PDA to Player

```
      let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
          self.system_program.to_account_info(), 
          system_program::Transfer {
              from: self.withdraw_fund.to_account_info(),
              to: self.player.to_account_info(),
          });
      system_program::transfer(cpi_context, amount)?;
```

The operator can airdop sol to PDA account "withdraw_fund" on timely basis to keepup with the withdrawal request.

Is this approach sensible/possible? What is other/appropriate way to implement above feature of transfer of sol from house wallet to players without the program saving private key of house wallet which is a security issue?

Comment: If your program is withdrawing lamports from a PDA of the program, no need to invoke the system transfer. You can just debit the PDA account and credit any type of account (program owned or system owned). Saves compute units as well. https://solanacookbook.com/references/programs.html#how-to-transfer-sol-in-a-program

Comment: Thank you above issue was resolved by using debit and credit like in the example.